# Custom authentication attribute Xamarin Froms

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributes, xamarin.forms, owin

I use my Owin auth provider on API service and RESTful controllers in my Xamarin Froms application.

I already have login method, and test page.

I whant to use some action filter attribute in xamarin forms.

on my first page, named TestPage i use, XAML view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MCHS.MobileApp.Views.TestPage">
  <Label Text="Test" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="TestMessageContainer"/>
</ContentPage>
```

and code for this page:

```
[Authentication]
    public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
    {

        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var response = App.client.GetAsync(LoginModel.ApiUrl+ "/api/test/get?id=5").Result;

            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            this.TestMessageContainer.Text = content;
        }
    }
```

In this service i use Authentication custom attribute, this attribute must do some logic of application and accept method or redirect user on another page view (LoginPage)

i use it like this :

```
 public class Authentication : Attribute
    {
        public Authentication()
        {

            //get device account info
            Account account = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(App.AppName).FirstOrDefault();

            //Check if access token in account
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(account.Properties["AccessToken"]))
            {
                //check token for expire
                if (DateTime.Parse(account.Properties["ExpiresIn"]) > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    new Authorization(new LoginModel()
                    {
                        Login = account.Username
                    });
                 }


                using (App.client)
                {
                    //New requset option
                    var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "grant_type", "refresh_token"},
                        { "refresh_token", account.Properties["RefreshToken"]}
                    };

                    var uri = new Uri(String.Format(LoginModel.ApiUrl + "token"));

                    //get response fo refreshed token
                    var tokenResponse = App.client.PostAsync(uri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form)).Result;

                    //Reinitialize static object for token response
                    App.ResponseToken = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;

                    account.Properties.Add("AccessToken", App.ResponseToken.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("AccessToken").GetValue("AccessToken").ToString());
                    account.Properties.Add("RefreshToken", App.ResponseToken.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("RefreshToken").GetValue("RefreshToken").ToString());
                    account.Properties.Add("ExpiresIn", App.ResponseToken.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("ExpiresIn").GetValue("ExpiresIn").ToString());

                    App.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                    App.ResponseToken.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("AccessToken").GetValue("AccessToken").ToString());
                    App.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                }
            }

            new Authorization(new LoginModel());
        }

    }
```

and now the problem.

Then i initialize my app, he load TestPage, but not give control to Authentication custom attribute, my system ignore it. 
What i`m doing wrong ?